# 3 level dropdown menu in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My menu data is like this.

```
Faculties
     Engineering
          Computer
          Electronic
     Medical  
          Some
     Economy
          Some1
          Some2
```

I want to show this in bootstrap nav bar. The socond level dropdown is not appearing.

```
 <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Faculties<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-bind="foreach: data.Fakulties">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-bind="text: name"><b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-bind="foreach: Departments">
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#" data-bind="text: name"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Comment: Try this link http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3

Answer (score 1):

here is the link for your problem,
please check this...http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3

Comment: the thisrd level menu is populating mouse hower. is there populating by click? because mobile devices has not hover.